# on pressing back button the activities should retain its state with its title

Tags: android

I am new to android. And my question is as below.

I am making an app in which there is a drawer which has multiple activities. For example say tv, refrigerator, mobile phone etc. No on clicking on the respective devices the page with the title opens. For example if click on tv its settings gets opened with the title tv. Now if i open over devices simultaneously its settings gets opened. But if i press back button the title of the settings gets merged.

Can anyone please help me out with this. As what to do to store its state and the correct title when back button is pressed in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed method as u desire...

Answer (score 0):

You can handle back button like this in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and save what ever you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

Better you define Action bar title in onResume() of each fragment/Activity.